# Purpose of byte and short primitive types in Java

Tags: java

I'm wondering about one issue related to primitive types in Java. When *short* and *byte* types are compiled into *int* primitive type by VM, then what is the purpose of using those types?

Comment: Why do you think `short` and `byte` are compiled to `int`? (really would be pretty pointless, if they were)

Comment: Although there is no no bytecode to do arithmetic with short or byte and they are casted to int at the jvm level, you can't know for sure how it is threated by the machine code, which is what really matter in this case. Just remember that bytecode is not machine code, and bytecodes are compiled by the JIT compiler.

Comment: Likewise, loads from arrays of values of type boolean, byte, short, and
char are encoded using Java virtual machine instructions that sign-extend or zero
extend the values to values of type int. Thus, most operations on values of actual
types boolean, byte, char, and short are correctly performed by instructions
operating on values of computational type int. (from The Java™ Virtual Machine Specification)

Comment: @zawart the specification doesn't explain how the jvm should work internally because it is implementation specific. The bytecode is casting bytes into ints but an implementation, at low-level, could be working with bytes.

Comment: @zawart: Right, _operations_ are performed on `int` values, which is quite different from saying that `short` and `byte` are compiled to `int` (effectively saying they don't exist in the JVM).  They're still _stored_ as the smaller values, so a `short[]`, for example, will use 2 bytes per element, not 4.

Answer (score 4):

They behave as bytes or shorts and are verified as bytes or shorts.

Example1 :

```
    byte b = 122;
    System.out.println((byte)(b*5)); // outputs 98
```

Example2 :

```
    byte b = 1422; // doesn't compile
```

From [the specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1) :

> The values of the integral types are integers in the following ranges:
>
> For byte, from -128 to 127, inclusive
>
> For short, from -32768 to 32767, inclusive
>
> For int, from -2147483648 to 2147483647, inclusive
>
> For long, from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807, inclusive
>
> For char, from '\u0000' to '\uffff' inclusive, that is, from 0 to
>   65535

You may have been confused by the fact that [numerical operations on integers always result in an int or a long](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2) (that is the result of `a*b` were `a` and `b` are of type `byte` is an `int`). Or by the fact that memory can be aligned and waste some place. But a `byte` and a `short` really don't overflow the same way than an `int` does.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that byte and short are promoted into int by JVM but it is only when they are used as local variables in the bytecode, in methods. But as fields

```
private byte field1;
private short field2;
```

they will occupy 1 and 2 bytes correspondingly.

Bytes are extremely important in Java becasuse they are used in byte arrays, first of all for input / output operations, like in java.io.InputStream.read(byte[] bytes)

As for short, it is rarely used, though it may be useful for storing large amounts of relatively small numbers, for memory economy

Answer (score 0):

For **network communications** and **image processing** you need bytes. And they are treated as `bytes`. If they were not then it would be pointless.

Comment: I was wondering what are applications of those types. I know the differences in java lang specification. In regard to bytes why not to use integers? The result will be the same in example which has been presented above.

Answer (score 0):

byte and short are not compiled as int's, they just fit into int. i.e,, you can assign a byte value into an int variable.

```
byte b=5;
int i = b;
```

but not the other way around unless you cast it explicitly

```
int i=4;
    byte b = i; //compiler error 

int i=4;
    byte b = (byte)i;
```

Comment: Please have a look at my quote above from virtual machine specification.